# Primary Key Violation on JPA save method

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm facing an annoying problem, which I think it's really stupid.
I'm using an H2 database with JPA and Hibernate.
This is my save method on ScheduleService.class:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public int save(Schedule sched) {
    try {
        scheduleRepository.save(sched);
    } catch(Exception e) {...}
}
```

The sentence "scheduleRepository.save(sched)" is throwing the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["UK_4R97H1MMVBOG9TD05OH9FKL16_INDEX_5 ON PUBLIC.SCHEDULE(CHANNEL, PROGRAMME, START, END) VALUES ( /* key:65574 */ null, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-15 17:00:00.0', null, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-15 16:40:00.0', 3, 13)"; SQL statement:
insert into schedule (channel, end, programme, published, start, idSched) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-175]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

And printing to the output console the following message:

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_4R97H1MMVBOG9TD05OH9FKL16_INDEX_5 ON PUBLIC.SCHEDULE(CHANNEL, PROGRAMME, START, END) VALUES ( /* key:65574 */ null, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-15 17:00:00.0', null, TIMESTAMP '2015-09-15 16:40:00.0', 3, 13)"; SQL statement:
insert into schedule (channel, end, programme, published, start, idSched) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-175]
```

I've removed my **@UniqueConstraint** annotation in Schedule entity to make sure it is not a unique constraint problem.
The error persists, so it must be caused by a primary key violation.
This is how I define the primary key of Schedule entity:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "idSched", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
protected Long idSched;
```

It should be assigning a new unique idSched field for every row is inserted in the table, right?

What could be the problem which is causing the exception?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Based on Bohuslav suggestion, I've changed the primary key declaration as this:

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(
    name="scheduleGen",
    table="schedule_sequence_table",
    pkColumnValue="idSched",
    allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator="scheduleGen")
@Column(name = "idSched", nullable = false)
protected Long idSched;
```

For the moment it seems to work fine.

**UPDATE 2:** Based on Sreenath comment:

I'm generating the tables only once (they're persisted as files on disk). Actually there was a unique key constraint on schedule table. However, since it was throwing that exception, I removed the constraint and removed database files to make sure the problem was not in the unique constraint but in the primary key instead. Even without the unique constraint and a brand new database, the exception still remained, so then I came with the @TableGenerator solution. Apparently that solved the problem.
But then I put my unique constraint again, removed database files so tables can be regenerated, and started and stopped the application a few times.
Now the problem has come again. 
This is my unique constraint:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"channel", "programme", "start", "end"})})
@Entity(name = "schedule")
public class Schedule { ...}
```

Of course, before I save an entity, I check if there is any other entity with the same unique members as the one I'm adding:

```
Schedule schedIn = schedRep.findOneByChannelAndProgrammeAndStartAndEnd(
                        sched.getChannel(), sched.getProgramme(), sched.getStart(), sched.getEnd());
// Check if there exists any schedule with the same {channel, programme, start, end} values                     
if (schedIn == null) {
    // If not, then save it
    schedRep.save(sched);
}
```

The method schedRep.findOneByChannelAndProgrammeAndStartAndEnd() is automatically generated by JPA. So that's weird, that query cannot find any schedule with the same {channel, programme, start, end} values, but when I try to save them, the unique constraint is violated.

Where could be the problem then?

Comment: If you use table generation strategy you should probably define table generator: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TableGenerator.html

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I've updated my post. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Are you generating the tables each and every time or only once?, if you are generating only once then you may still have unique key constraint in your table even removed from the entity. Can you cross check if there is any unique constraint in your table?

Comment: @SreenathReddy I've updated my question. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Are you doing bulk insertion?, i.e inserting large data in a single transaction. Why I am asking is you are saying findOneByChannelAndProgrammeAndStartAndEnd() method can not find any results with unique key set, but when you are tryinig to save it is throwing exception. Also please check the entries in the data base if there are any results which can cause this exception.

Comment: Yes, I was doing bulk insertion. Then I modified my code so insert single records within a @Transactional method. However, the problem keep happening. It was trying to insert a record which was already in the database. The DB also suffered some corruption problems sometimes. So I decided to replace the embedded H2 with a local MySQL. Now it's working fine. So it seems that H2 was not managing transactions between different threads very well.